# Python code crashes within try except block

Tags: python

I am using a cloud platform to run a program and my code crashes when it runs into an error that is within a try/except block. I do not know if it is due to the platform, but I need a way to avoid the program from crashing.

```
try:

    r = self.http.request('GET', 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTADAY&symbol=VIX&interval=1min&apikey=apikey')
    data = json.loads(r.data)

    if 'Time Series (1min)' in data.keys():
        self.VIX = Decimal(data['Time Series (1min)'][list(data['Time Series (1min)'].keys())[0]]['4. close'])
    else:  
        raise Exception("key")


except Exception as e:

    self.Debug('VIX Error: ' + str(e))

    try:
        r = self.http.request('GET', 'https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=VIX&i=60&p=1d&f=c')   #f=d,o,h,l,c,v'
        s = (r.data).decode('utf-8')
        l = list(s.splitlines())
        self.VIX = Decimal(l[-1])

    except Exception as e:

        self.Debug('VIX Error: ' + str(e))  #change after last deployment

        if (type(self.VIX) is Decimal) == False:
            self.VIX = 0
```

> LiveTradingRealTimeHandler.Run(): There was an error in a scheduled
>   event QuantConnect.Scheduling.ScheduledEvent. The error was
>   UnicodeDecodeError : 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position
>   57360: invalid start byte
>
> Runtime Error: UnicodeDecodeError : 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte
>   0xa0 in position 57405: invalid start byte at OnData in main.py:line
>   417 at GetVix in main.py:line 458 UnicodeDecodeError : 'utf-8' codec
>   can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 57405: invalid start byte Stack
>   Trace: System.Exception: UnicodeDecodeError : 'utf-8' codec can't
>   decode byte 0xa0 in position 57405: invalid start byte at OnData in
>   main.py:line 417 at GetVix in main.py:line 458 --->
>   Python.Runtime.PythonException: UnicodeDecodeError : 'utf-8' codec
>   can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 57405: invalid start byte at
>   Python.Runtime.PyObject.Invoke (Python.Runtime.PyTuple args,
>   Python.Runtime.PyDict kw) [0x00033] in
>   <7ada479175184ff388929ece541bbdb4>:0 at
>   Python.Runtime.PyObject.InvokeMethod (System.String name,
>   Python.Runtime.PyTuple args, Python.Runtime.PyDict kw) [0x00007] in
>   <7ada479175184ff388929ece541bbdb4>:0 at
>   Python.Runtime.PyObject.TryInvokeMember
>   (System.Dynamic.InvokeMemberBinder binder, System.Object[] args,
>   System.Object& result) [0x0003e] in
>   <7ada479175184ff388929ece541bbdb4>:0 at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:CallSite.Target
>   (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,QuantConnect.Data.Slice)
>   at
>   QuantConnect.AlgorithmFactory.Python.Wrappers.AlgorithmPythonWrapper.OnData
>   (QuantConnect.Data.Slice slice) [0x00088] in :0 at
>   QuantConnect.Lean.Engine.AlgorithmManager.Run
>   (QuantConnect.Packets.AlgorithmNodePacket job,
>   QuantConnect.Interfaces.IAlgorithm algorithm,
>   QuantConnect.Lean.Engine.DataFeeds.IDataFeed feed,
>   QuantConnect.Lean.Engine.TransactionHandlers.ITransactionHandler
>   transactions, QuantConnect.Lean.Engine.Results.IResultHandler results,
>   QuantConnect.Lean.Engine.RealTime.IRealTimeHandler realtime,
>   QuantConnect.Lean.Engine.Server.ILeanManager leanManager,
>   QuantConnect.Lean.Engine.Alpha.IAlphaHandler alphas,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x013e5] in :0 --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Side question, why do you say `if (type(self.VIX) is Decimal) == False:` instead of `if not isinstance(self.VIX, Decimal):`?

Comment: plase post the full error traceback formatted, it is likely to show the line where the error comes from

Comment: @EdwardMinnix I guess it might be better to do `if not isinstance(self.VIX, Decimal):`. I am not a professional coder so I often just find a way that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When catching an exception in Python, or any language for that matter, you need to be very clear which exceptions to catch or your program will still crash.  You're catching `Exception` but your program is crashing from a `UnicodeDecodeError` so you should try catching that error and handling it appropriately.

Try something like this `except UnicodeDecodeError as e:`

Comment: `except (Exception, UnicodeDecodeError) as e:` seems pointless? `Exception` is the base of everything, would would be better is catching several more specific exceptions no?

Comment: but Exception is the base class of other exceptions (which is based on BaseException), so it should catch any kind of well implemented exception

Comment: But `UnicodeDecodeError` is a subclass of `Exception`, so it is possible to catch it. Try the minimal example `try:
    raise UnicodeDecodeError('1',b'2',3,4,'5')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)`

Comment: I'll try this, but could you tell me why sometimes `Exception as e` will catch it and why sometimes I would have to add the specific exception?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks,  I was actually questioning all my knowledge on `Exception` with these up votes.

Comment: @Pier-OlivierMarquis when you know which specific exceptions are raised, it is better to be narrower in your usage. This can be more helpful to the reader, since it helps understand what could happen. It also is useful because sometimes you need to handle different errors in different ways. `except Exception:` is usually considered bad practice

Comment: Yes this is what I'm really trying to get at Edward, that specificity is key to debugging.  Using specific exceptions will help the OP with knowing what errors to expect in his code and better handle the errors when they arise.

Comment: @J0hn I tried this and it works. I also believed like Chris_Rands that the base exception should catch it, but apparently I had to specify it. Thanks.

Comment: @Pier-OlivierMarquis What you're saying makes no sense to me, can you create a minimal example that illustrates this behaviour?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Actually, it is not clear to me as well. I can run the example above in VS Code or any Python IDE and it works, but on the cloud platform that I am using it crashes.  It might be something specific to the platform, but it still solved my problem.

Comment: @Pier-OlivierMarquis I am convinced *something else* solved your issue

Comment: @Chris_Rands Well, I literally added `except (Exception, UnicodeDecodeError) as e:` as J0hn suggested and that's it...

Comment: @Pier-OlivierMarquis What you're claiming would seem like a bug in Python, instead I imagine something else in your cloud environment/data has changed

Comment: I am facing a similar issue where in when I run code through any idea try catch block works but when I directly run the file it crashes. I am too using base class Exception. However, what I am doing is connecting sql server through pyodbc.